# Application calling service reference with old configuration (localhost) instead of hosted service address

Tags: visual-studio-2012, service, configuration, reference

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 Application that is calling two WCF Services. Initially, I had the services running from a seperate project locally.

I added service reference to http://local.host:28089/ServiceName1.svc and /ServiceName2.svc

There is a no "." between local and host. Stackoverflow is not letting me type local.host.
At this point of time, I had two instances of VS2012 running. One was running the services and the other was running the Front-end application which was calling these services. Everything worked fine.
Both were hosted using IIS Express which comes with VS2012.

Then I hosted my services on a server machine. I deleted the service references on the UI App on my local machine and then added the new service references. I can also see the hosted services on my local machine using the browser.

The web.config was automatically updated with new end-points.

But when I run my application and expect it to call the hosted services, it instead throws an error saying "There was no endpoint listening at http://local.host:28089/ServiceName1.svc

I don't understand why and from where it is still calling the old configuration. I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, removing-and readding service references, restarting VS, restarting my system but to no avail.

Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by right-click on IIS Express in taskbar and clicking "Stop-All" , cleaning solution. Going to properties of my project and using VS Server instead of IIS Express and then rebuilding.